# Can one instruct MS Teams to hide the loading indicator from a MVC (ASP.NET) App?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

The MS Teams `JavaScript client SDK` can instruct the Microsoft Teams Application to hide it's loading spinner with the following command: `microsoftTeams.appInitialization.notifySuccess();`

I'm looking for a similar method to call from my MVC ASP.NET Application.

Is there a way to do this? Thanks in advance !

```
import * as microsoftTeams from '@microsoft/teams-js';
 
@Injectable()
export class Service {

    myMethodName() {
        microsoftTeams.appInitialization.notifySuccess(); // 
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you tried to call notifyAppLoaded() method before success method?

Comment: Yes I did. The notifySuccess() method is working in from my Angular app.
But I would like to call notifySuccess() or notifyAppLoaded() from an MVC (asp.net) application. This seems impossible. Feels kind of stange as notifySuccess() is a method which calls to the Microsoft graph, and Microsoft MVC asp.net doesn't have a nugget package for it..

Comment: You can import teams library in your MVC application by script tag notifyAppLoaded will be accessible  after your initialize teams library, Microsoft graph can be installed from nuget pkg manager: Install-Package Microsoft.Graph -Version 3.19.0

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We tried searching for notifyAppLoaded in the microsoft graph (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) but were not successfull. Could you try to explain more explicitly?

Comment: Did you tried to put the notifyAppLoaded in script tag after initialize the teams client SDK

Comment: I proposed the solution. My senior didn't approve of it because we use a asp.net mini app in an Angular app. Thanks for the help though! Learned a new thing!

Comment: If this helped you, please spare a minute and give your [Feedback](https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=v4j5cvGGr0GRqy180BHbR7iCOpS5_b9Nqmwx43u5rtZUOThVR081SllSR05aSDQxQ0tUMDVPTVIxTi4u). Thank you